# Overloaded and overridden in Java

Tags: java, overriding, computer-science, overloading

I know how to overload a method, and how to override a method. But is that possible to overload AND override a method at the same time? If yes, please give an example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Overloading and overriding are complementary things, overloading means the same method name but different parameters, and overriding means the same method name in a subclass with the same parameters. So its not possible for overloading and overriding to happen at the same time because overloading implies different parameters.

Examples:

```
class A {
    public void doSth() { /// }
}

class B extends A {
    public void doSth() { /* method overriden */ }

    public void doSth(String b) { /* method overloaded */ }

}
```

Cheers!

Comment: If you want to, you can override an overloaded method. It's as close as it can get.

Comment: When this happens, which is responsible for the binding (in terms of static or dynamic) of the method then? Overriding or overloading?

Answer (score 6):

overloading and overloading are just abstractions. Overloading just means the compiler uses the name in conjunction with the types and number of parameters for addressing what function to call. In reality overloading a method is no different than naming it something different because the key the compiler uses to look up the function is a combination of name and parameter list.

Overriding is kind of the same principle except the compiler can address the overriden function with the `super` keyword.

So can you override an overloaded function? Yes, since the overloaded method is a completely  different method in the eyes of the compiler.

Comment: Overriding isn't the same thing at all. The decision as to which method to call is deferred to runtime. The compiler doesn't decide it.

Comment: @EJP - Ultimately the compiler makes the decision even if its abstracted through the construction of a vtables and assignment of vpointers to facilitate dynamic dispatch. The ties that bind have to be initialized somewhere.

Comment: @EJP - secondly if you read closely you'll see all that I said is that the compiler will treat overloaded methods as completely different methods because the compiler uses the name and the parameter list to form a key. This absolutely plays a role in the dynamic dispatch initialization process at compile time. As for the last bit, go ahead and add an `override` annotation to an overloaded  method in a subclass with a `final` modifier and see if the compiler decides to get involved

Comment: @nsfyn55 The compiler cannot possibly be said to make the decision when the decision can involve classes that the compiler isn't seeing at the time that it is alleged to do so. What the compiler does it to generate code which *in conjunction with* the runtime system or runtime library ensures that the correct method is called. This is not the same thing as the compiler making the decision. It is also not the same thing as the compiler deciding among overloads, contrary to your statement above in your answer.

Comment: @EJP-ugh. I'm not even sure what you are talking about. The call is virtual, but it still lays down a jump instruction it just happens to jump somewhere else once it gets there. It does lay down two different addresses for overloaded methods because they are completely different methods. Implementations are irrelevant. All I am saying is that overloading only exists because the compiler doesn't key off just the name, but it does make special consideration for the `super` keyword when overriding methods.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean.  A method can be an override for an overloaded method in a superclass.  And you can overload a method that you are simultaneously overriding using another method.

However, you cannot have one method that is both a *new* overload and an override.  For a method to be an override, another method with the same signature must already exist in the superclass ... and that means that this method cannot be a *new* override.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can overload and override a function in the same class but you would not be able to overload a function in two different classes as it is logically not possible.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Base {
   public:
    void print() 
    {
        cout << "Base Function" << endl;
    }
    void print(string name) //Overloaded Function
    {
        cout << "Base Function : " <<name<< endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
   public:
    void print() 
    {
        cout << "Derived Function" << endl;
    }
     void print(string name) //Overloaded Function
    {
        cout << "Derived Function : "<<name<< endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived derived1, derived2;
   
    //accesses the print function in derived class
    derived1.print();
   
    //accesses the overloaded print function in derived class
    derived1.print("Gitanshu");
    
    //accesses the print function in base class
    derived2.Base::print();

    //accesses the overloaded print function in base class
    derived2.Base::print("Gitanshu");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Derived Function
Derived Function : Gitanshu
Base Function
Base Function : Gitanshu
```

I answered it using C++, The same would apply in Java as well.